# Return n number of lines after grep match from large files

Tags: bash, grep, pattern-matching, large-files

I have two large files. One file has a list of lines that I am grepping in another file. I found that the following code works great to pull out matching lines in File2 along with the 3 lines after the match in a short test file.

When I try to run the same code on large files, 15 million lines for File1 and 63 million lines for File2, the process is taking, understandably, a very long time.

Is there anyway to do this faster?

Code:

```
grep -A 3 -xf File1 File2
```

File1 data example:

```
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15033:1350 1:N:0:0
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:16062:1339 1:N:0:0
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15860:1331 1:N:0:0
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15810:1334 1:N:0:0
```

File2 data example:

```
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15860:1331 1:N:0:0
TGAGTCACTGGT
+
BBCBBFFFFFFD
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15655:1332 1:N:0:0
TCCGACACAATT
+
ABB3ADDBFAFF
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15831:1332 1:N:0:0
GACTTGGTATTC
+
A111>1C113B@
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15598:1332 1:N:0:0
CCTCGTTCGACT
+
BCCCCDDFCBCD
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15810:1334 1:N:0:0
GCTGCTGAGCAT
+
>111111BF111
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15895:1334 1:N:0:0
CCTCGTTCGACT
+
>A1>>1>C11?>
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:16015:1334 1:N:0:0
AATCAGTCTCGT
+
AAAA?@B@BD1>
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15715:1335 1:N:0:0
AATCAGTCTCGT
+
BCBCCFFFFFFC
@M02465:48:000000000-A94WY:1:1101:15455:1335 1:N:0:0
AGGCTACACGAC
+
AABAAFFFFBBB
```

Comment: Of course it takes a long amount of time.
You can test [ack](http://beyondgrep.com) an equivalant to grep

Comment: @maggick: `ack` can be faster than `grep` because it avoids searching in useless files.  That won't help here.  Actually, GNU `grep` is one of the most carefully optimised tool for this.

Comment: okay, so the fgrep response from @lcd047 seems the best one.

Comment: Can you compress both files and upload both somewhere to test this?

Comment: This is the best you're going to do with an unindexed file.

Comment: I tested and fgrep was much faster. My File1 did not have duplicates, so I just ran fgrep instead of grep.

Comment: How are you storing the output? Is it going to the terminal? To a local file?

Comment: The output is going into a file

`fgrep -A 3 -xf File1 File2 > File3`

Answer (score 3):

Use `fgrep` instead of `grep`.  Much faster if you don't need to match regular expressions:

```bash
fgrep -A 3 -xf File1 File2
```

Making sure your pattern file `File1` doesn't contain duplicates might help too:

```bash
sort -u File1 >File1_new
```

Comment: Thanks lcd047, fgrep was much faster in this case!